# Android Canvas drawText consistent on different screens

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawtext

I'm making an app where I want to draw text on an image. This text should be positioned exactly according to figures on the image. I know exactly from which pixel I want to draw in the original img. But when doing this the text varies in position and size depending on the screen.

Is there a way do draw on a bitmap, independent of screen size and such?
Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
...
    Bitmap imgFront = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.card_front,options);
    List<StringDrawer> sds = new LinkedList<StringDrawer>();        
    ImageGenerator ig = new ImageGenerator(imgFront);
    ig.process(sds);
    BitmapDrawable bgd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),imgFront);
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(bgd);
...

public class ImageGenerator {
    Bitmap image;
    public ImageGenerator(Bitmap image){
        this.image = image;
    }
    public void process(List<StringDrawer> strings) {
        Canvas c = new Canvas(image);
        for(StringDrawer sd:strings){
        sd.draw(c);
        }

    }
}

public class StringDrawer {
    private String text;
    private int x, y, size, style;
    private int color;

    public StringDrawer(int x, int y, int size, int style, int color,
            String text) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
        this.text = text;
        this.style = style;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw(Canvas c) {
        c.save();
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAlpha(0);
        p.setTypeface(Typeface.create("Arial", style));
        p.setTextSize(size);
        p.setColor(color);
        c.rotate(90, x, y);
        c.drawText(text, x, y, p);
        c.restore();
    }
}
```

After some reading and understanding what dp is I came to the conclusion that this is all that is needed(put in StringDrawer to convert x, y and size):

```
private int pxToDp(int px){
        return (int) (px * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

Comment: The `x` `y` are in px. Are you using the device density `dp` to calculate the px value?

Comment: Right now I have a few manually created StringDrawers with x, y set to match the resolution of the original image. How would I calculate the pixels according to the device?

Comment: I wrote this library, which basically draws text on a drawable. You could take a look at the sample and see how its done. Specifically the `toPx()` method at the bottom: https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/amulyakhare/td/sample/sample/DrawableProvider.java#L142